# Extraer caracteres entre paréntesis R

Tags: r, string, substring

Estoy trabajando con un campo que recoge la población y entre paréntesis la provincia y deseo quedarme solamente con la provincia, es decir, lo que va entre paréntesis.

Pongo unos ejemplos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado extraerlo con las variantes de substr o substring pero no he sido capaz ya que exigen una posición inicial y aquí va variando.

He intentado también meterme con expresiones regulares pero no he sacado nada en claro buscando por Internet.

No sé si alguien podrá ayudarme con esto porque no he encontrado nada por ahí.

Gracias!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En este caso, antes de las expresiones regulares, puedes optar por soluciones más sencillas, por ejemplo:

```
x <- c('MARTORELL(BARCELONA)', 'MADRID(MADRID)', 'sin provincia')
strsplit(sub('[)]', '', x), '[(]')

[[1]]
[1] "MARTORELL" "BARCELONA"

[[2]]
[1] "MADRID" "MADRID"

[[3]]
[1] "sin provincia"
```

Esto, elimina el paréntesis fina y usa el del comienzo como separador, con lo que conseguimos dividir las dos partes de cada cadena, luego, podemos hacer:

```
sapply(strsplit(sub('[)]', '', x), '[(]'), `[`, 2)
[1] "BARCELONA" "MADRID"    NA
```

dónde a cada elemento de la lista, le extraemos el segundo ítem de cada vector, reemplazar `x` por la columna de tu `data.frame` sería todo para extraer la provincia.

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio! Al final sí que logré sacarlo con expresiones regulares, pero aún así muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

He logrado resolverlo con gsub finalmente, dejo a continuación un ejemplo por si a alguien le sirve en el futuro:

```
> x <- "bilbao(vizcaya)"
> 
> gsub("[\\(\\)]", "", regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\(.*?\\)", x))[[1]])
[1] "vizcaya"
```

Answer (score 1):

Una opción usando sólo `gsub()` y regex.

```r
texto <- c("TAVERNES BLANQU(VALENCIA)", "MADRID(MADRID)", "Ateixo(LA CORUÑA)", 
           "Alcobendas(MADRID)")

gsub(x = texto, pattern = ".*(?<=\\()|\\)", replacement = "", perl = TRUE)

[1] "VALENCIA"  "MADRID"    "LA CORUÑA" "MADRID"
```

La expresión regular eliminará el texto que corresponde con lo siguiente y lo reemplazará con `""` :

- `.*(?<=\\()` : Cualquier cantidad de caracteres `.*` que se encuentran antes de un `(` que escapamos con `\\`, utilizando lookbehind `(?<=)`.
- `|` : O...
- `\\)$` : Busca un `)` al final de una cadena `$` que escapamos con `\\`.

Necesitamos indicar `perl = TRUE` para poder usar `lookbehind` y su complemento, `lookahead`.

De este modo, el resultado será solo el texto entre paréntesis.